# Error with WebApi RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is my prefix attribute

```
 [RoutePrefix("news/farms")]
 public class farmsController : ApiController
```

I want to delete a row based on farmid but i want a url structure like this

`/news/farms/{farmId}?version={Version}`

I tried route url like below code

```
 [HttpDelete, Route("{farmId}?version={Version}", Name = "Deletefarm")]
```

But it shows

```
The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
```

Please anyone let me know is there any other way to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `RoutePrefix` like in your example:

```
[RoutePrefix("news/farms")]
public class FarmsController : ApiController
```

And your delete Methode:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{farmId}")]
public void Delete(int farmId, string version)
```

Then this should work:

> .../news/farms/1?version=myVersion

Answer (score 0):

why would you try to add the version in the route as a query param? Is this not something you want in your controller routing?

nevertheless:
will this work?

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id, [FromQuery] string version)
{
 //...your code
}
```

with the `[FromQuery]` you specify that you want it from the.... query ;)

Answer (score 0):

URI path cannot have a query string in it so it is not allowed, refer - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

For your answer what you want is  -

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult DeleteFarm(int farmId, [FromQuery] string version)
{
    //
}
```